# Booktabs multicolumn, vertical lines between columns

Tags: formatting, booktabs

I'm still new to latex and having some trouble with my tables. I have to make a table in the format below (e.g., specific line thickeness, double lines below column headers, and vertical lines between columns). How can I extend the vertical lines between the columns in my headers that use multicolumn?

If this is not possible with booktabs, what is another package that works well with mult columns and multi rows?

```
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{array}
% \newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\def\toprule{\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}}
\def\botrule{\toprule}
\def\headerrule{\hline\hline}
\def\midrule{\specialrule{0.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{CAPTION.}

\begin{tabular}{C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{2cm}|C{4cm}C{4cm}}
\toprule

Column A & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Column B} & Column C & Column D \\
\cline{2-4}
& B1 & B2 & B3       \\
\headerrule

blah & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & blah & blah \\
\midrule
blah & \checkmark & -- & \checkmark & blah & blah \\

\botrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: read the booktabs package documentation. It by design makes vertical rules unusable. Choose booktabs or `|` do not use both.

Comment: please provide a small complete document not just  fragment so we do not have to guess definitions of `C` etc

Comment: perhaps you just want `& B1 & B2 & B3 & &       \\ ` so the row does not end short and the rules get drawn?

Comment: Thank you, using `Column A & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Column B} & Column C & Column D \\
\cline{2-4} & B1 & B2 & B3 & &  \\` works. I will accept it as an answer if you write it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide a usable example but it seems you just want

```
 & B1 & B2 & B3 & &       \\
```

so the row does not end short and the vertical rules get drawn

Answer (score 2):

For fun, but you may liked :-)

- With `tabularray` package you can define lines thickness in table preamble
- Columns width you can define absolutely or better as ration between width of `X` columns (as is done in MWE below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=sf, labelfont=bf,
            singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\newcommand\cm{\checkmark}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\sffamily
\caption{CAPTION.}

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, 
             hline{2,4-Z}=solid,
             hline{3} = {1}{-}{},
             hline{3} = {2}{-}{},
             vline{2-Y} = solid,
             colspec={ *{5}{X[c]} X[2,c] }
            }
\SetCell[r=2]{h}   Column A    
            & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Column B    
                    &       &       & \SetCell[r=2]{h}   Column C  
                                                & \SetCell[r=2]{h}   Column D  \\
            & B1    & B2    & B3    &           &           \\

blah        & \cm   & \cm   & \cm   & blah      & blah      \\
blah        & \cm   & --    & \cm   & blah      & blah      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]